# understanding why the data attribute values are set to null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just going through the code in [counterup.js](https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up/blob/master/jquery.counterup.js) and i came across the following lines of code :

```
            delete $this.data('counterup-nums');
            $this.data('counterup-nums', null);
            $this.data('counterup-func', null);
```

Of course this plugin uses data attributes for storing values, which it later uses for calculations. now my question is, not what are the above lines of code doing, but rather why the above lines of code at all ?

Ok the first line of code :

```
delete $this.data('counterup-nums');
```

Does make a little bit of sense, but what are the below lines of code doing at all

```
$this.data('counterup-nums', null);
$this.data('counterup-func', null);
```

?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.removeData/

Comment: I don't think `delete $this.data('counterup-nums');` does anything at all...  http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qdwb5avx/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was interesting. But i researched some interesting facts by writing the sample code as below.

```
 function hello(){
    var el = document.querySelector('#user');
    el.dataset.dateOfBirth = '1960-10-03';   
}


function undIt(){
 var el = document.querySelector('#user');
 el.dataset.dateOfBirth = undefined;    
}

hello()
alert(document.querySelector('#user').dataset.dateOfBirth)

undIt()
alert(document.querySelector('#user').dataset.dateOfBirth)

delete document.querySelector('#user').dataset.dateOfBirth;
```

Js Fiddler link http://jsfiddle.net/nirus/f92chmdp/1/

When i commented the **delete** statement i found that the dataset variable still persists in the DOM tree(Set as undefined string) see the below image[image]

When i un-commented the **delete** statement i could see its been removed from the DOM tree. See the image below
[image]

**Conclusion:** Author has used delete keyword to completely remove the reference of the data variable and its persistence.

**----------------------------***** Based on the comment by user guest271314 ******------------------**

I did some research again and yes jQuery implementation is different. So to achieve the above for jQuery code see the below.(Author should have implemented like below code) [Jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/nirus/f92chmdp/2/)

```
   $(function(){
    function hello(){
        var el = $('#user');
        el.data('dateOfBirth','1960-10-03');
    }


    function undIt(){
        var el = $('#user');
        el.data('dateOfBirth',null);    
    }

    alert($('#user').data('dateOfBirth'))

    hello()
    alert($('#user').data('dateOfBirth'))

    undIt()
    alert($('#user').data('dateOfBirth'))

    //delete document.querySelector('#user').dataset.dateOfBirth;
    //delete $('#user').data('dateOfBirth');
    delete jQuery.cache.data.dateOfBirth;

    alert($('#user').data('dateOfBirth')) //This line throws Error. Read Note: section
});
```

jQuery maintains a cache variable called **jQuery.cache.data** and stores the key/value under this hood to avoid performance overhead by querying the DOM and extracting the value. If you want to use HTML5 implementation of **data** API in jQuery use **.Attr()** API

**Note :** In the above code last line throws an error as value is removed and browsers cannot refer **undefined** or **null** object references in Object tree. Technically the variables and references are removed.

Comment: @Nirus Note , jQuery `.data()` https://api.jquery.com/data/ not appear dependent on `HTMLElement.dataset` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset ; two separate implementations ?

Comment: @guest271314 updated the answer by doing some more research based on your comment. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

[**delete**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete): The delete operator removes a property from an object.

I mayn't explain what `delete $this.data('counterup-nums');` line is doing, but may be author wants to clear every thing with this line. And i believe this `delete` keyword doesn't make sense  with `$this.data('counterup-nums')`. Instead of this `delete` i would have preferred `Jquery.removeData()` for removing `data` attribute from element.

But following like makes a sense:

```
$this.data('counterup-nums', null);
$this.data('counterup-func', null);
```

Author is setting data attributes to `null` so that next time he can easily identify, value is reset or not.